# Activity orientation doesn't get restored

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, screen-orientation

I have activity A that runs in an unspecified orientation. So it can run in both: portrait and landscape. I launch activity B that has to be landscape. In B's onCreate, I check current orientation, if it's portrait then I store it, and then I force landscape via setRequestedOrientation(). When B is done, I want A to appear in the orientation it was in before B was launched (so portrait).

This is where things don't work for me. On cleanup, I read the orientation value that I stored originally, and if it's portrait then I set B to portrait (via setRequestedOrientation()). I tried this in onPause and onDestroy of B. Nothing happens visually. Log reports (via getRequestedOrientation()) that the orientation was indeed changed. However activity A is coming back up in landscape instead of original portrait.

What's the dealio?

PS. Changing orientation back in activity A is not an option.

Comment: I guess no visual changes can occur in onPause or onDestroy.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but I think you can set `android:screenOrientation="     "` in the manifest for each Activity.